# JavaScript add styles to a div only when div class exists

Tags: javascript

Im trying to set some inline styles on some divs but only when the div and class exists in the page

basically, I have a slider and i want to apply the header height on some slider divs for adjustments, But this slider doesn't exist on every page so I want the JS to work only when the page has the slider and the class

I have tried my best with the below code but not sure why it doesn't work, Probably a silly mistake :) Big newbie here

```
var HeaderHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("Header").offsetHeight;
var slideContent = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-container");
var slideSwipes = document.getElementsByClassName("SwiperNav");
if (slideContent.length > 0 || slideSwipes.length > 0) {
  slideContent.style.paddingTop = HeaderHeight + "px";
  slideSwipes.style.top = HeaderHeight + "px";
}
```

BTW! IF you think there is a better way to do it Give a simple example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could iterate the element With `for loop` .`slideSwipes` and `slideContent` both are same length

```
var HeaderHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("Header");
var slideContent = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-container");
var slideSwipes = document.getElementsByClassName("SwiperNav");
if (slideContent.length > 0 || slideSwipes.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < slideSwipes.length; i++) {
    slideContent[i].style.paddingTop = HeaderHeight[i].offsetHeight + "px";
    slideSwipes[i].style.top = HeaderHeight[i].offsetHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

**Working example**

```js
var HeaderHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("Header");
var slideContent = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-container");
var slideSwipes = document.getElementsByClassName("SwiperNav");
if (slideContent.length > 0 || slideSwipes.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < slideSwipes.length; i++) {
    slideContent[i].style.paddingTop = HeaderHeight[i].offsetHeight + "px";
    slideSwipes[i].style.top = HeaderHeight[i].offsetHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
.slide-container{
height:50px;
}
.SwiperNav{
height:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Header">ssx
<div class="slide-container">sxs</div>
<div class="SwiperNav">sxs</div>
</div>
<div class="Header">ssx
<div class="slide-container">sxs</div>
<div class="SwiperNav">sxs</div>
</div>
<div class="Header">ssx
<div class="slide-container">sxs</div>
<div class="SwiperNav">sxs</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you check the code please? I get this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var :) Thank you btw

Comment: @Nippledisaster .see my updated answer.i forget the `k`

Comment: @Nippledisaster .see my updated answer .i was added working example both length are a same.Better use one variable

Comment: Thank you very very much :)

Answer (score 1):

It not working becouse `document.getElementsByClassName("slide-container");` return **array** of DOM elements, so if you want add style for first element you should select this list:

```
var HeaderHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("Header")[0].offsetHeight;
var slideContent = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-container")[0];
var slideSwipes = document.getElementsByClassName("SwiperNav")[0];
```

You could use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the presence of the DOM elements using document.body.contains(ELEMENT); where you can get the ELEMENT using the tag name or id or class name..and appy this inside your logic